# ¿Cómo es recomendable implementar un combobox de nacionalidades?

Tags: python, django, csv

Quiero implementar un combobox que contenga nacionalidades para el registro de una página web desarrollada con Django.

¿Cuál es la mejor manera para manejar la gran cantidad de opciones y mostrarlas en el combobox?

Comment: Te recomiendo mostrarlas en un select como tal, pero, como pueden ser muchas, podrías apoyarte en la librería [Select2](https://select2.org/) de jquery, ésta te permite cargar el contenido del select2 vía ajax, y paginado, así no tienes que imprimirlas todas de golpe sino que puedes implementar un filtrado dependiendo de lo que vayan escribiendo, en la documentación tiene una sección de [remote data](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) que te puede servir de ejemplo.

Comment: ok muchas gracias, investigaré.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más sencillo es usar [django-countries](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries). Todo está documentado pero acá van los pasos:

1. Lo instalas:

   ```
   pip install django-countries
   ```
2. Lo agregas a tu `INSTALLED_APPS`:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       # ...
       'django_countries'
   )
   ```
3. Agregas el campo a tu modelo:

   ```
   from django.db import models
   from django_countries.fields import CountryField

   class MiModelo(models.Model):
       # ...
       pais = CountryField()
   ```
4. **(Opcional)** Si quieres que se muestra una banderita en el país puedes usar el widget `CountrySelectWidget`:

   ```
   from django_countries.widgets import CountrySelectWidget

   class MiModeloForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = MiModelo
           fields = ('...', 'pais')
           widgets = {'pais': CountrySelectWidget()}
   ```

Los países se guardan usando el ISO 3166-1 así que en el caso de Perú, por ejemplo, se guardará como `PE`.